# IF OR NOT ISBLANK Formula nesting help

Tags: formula, formula-field

I have a formula to calculate renewal upsell only if the Previous Renewal lookup isn't blank. I want it to also only run if Type (picklist) = Renewals.

```
IF(OR(NOT(ISBLANK(Previous_Renewal__r.Name)), ISPICKVAL(Type,"Renewals")),Annual_Recurring_Revenue__c - Previous_Renewal__r.Annual_Recurring_Revenue__c,NULL)
```

The syntax is fine, but it's still running for other Types. Can anyone provide insight why?

Comment: Ah, the syntax is validating fine, but I think I might have an improper placement of ')'?

Comment: Can you try with AND condition instead of OR condition. Because the formula should work only if both satisfies

Comment: Oh gosh. Facepalm moment. THANK YOU!

Comment: I have updated the answer with the same . Thank You

Answer (score 1):

As the formula should return the value only if both the conditions satisfies you have to use `AND()` operator instead of `OR()` operator. So can you change the formula as below and check.

```
IF(AND(NOT(ISBLANK(Previous_Renewal__r.Name)), ISPICKVAL(Type,"Renewals")),Annual_Recurring_Revenue__c - Previous_Renewal__r.Annual_Recurring_Revenue__c,NULL)
```

`AND()` returns true if only both the values are true. But `OR()` returns true if any of the value is true.